# Rails/Arel: select case sum along with model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arel

I have a model called Post (table `posts`), which has a relationship with a model called User (table `users`), which is referenced as "uploader" in the Post model (the posts table has a column called `uploader_id` which is the `id` of the table users). An User can have many Posts, some of which can be deleted (marked through the `is_deleted` boolean column in `posts`).

How do I get a list of users with the number of total and deleted posts?

```
::Post
  .select(
    Arel.star.count.as("total"),
    Arel::Nodes::Case.new.when(Post.arel_table[:is_deleted]).then(1).sum.as("deleted_count"),
    :uploader
   )
  .joins(:uploader)
  .group(:uploader)
  .order(:total, :deleted_count)
  .limit(20)
```

This does not work. I need the user to be returned as model, the uploader_id is not sufficient.

I've tried many attempts at this but no matter what I do I can't figure it out. Either it tries to insert "#<Arel::Nodes::Count:0x0000565..." as a literal in the SQL string, or it returns arrays of nils.

What's extremely frustrating to me is that this works instead, if I only want the total posts and the user:

```
::Post
  .joins(:uploader)
  .group(:uploader)
  .order(Arel.sql("count(*) desc"))
  .limit(20)
  .count
```

I just can't figure out how to add the conditional case sum, I'm a novice at rails and the documentation does not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"How do I get a list of users with the number of total and deleted posts?"* seems like you are going about this in the wrong direction.
Better to start with `User` since you want `User` objects to be returned.

Also  `Post.arel_table[:is_deleted]` is not a condition this should be `Post.arel_table[:is_deleted].eq(1)` or whatever is "true" in your database.

Try the following instead:

```
User.left_joins(:posts)
  .select(
     User.arel_table[Arel.star],
     Post.arel_table[Arel.star].count.as('total_posts'),
     Arel::Nodes::Case.new 
       .when(Post.arel_table[:is_deleted].eq(1)).then(1)
       .else(0).sum.as('deleted_count'))
  .group(:id)
  .order(
    Post.arel_table[Arel.star].count, 
    Arel::Nodes::Case.new 
      .when(Post.arel_table[:is_deleted].eq(1)).then(1)
      .else(0).sum)
  .limit(20)
```

Comment: Good answer. If you're using Postgres you can use `count(posts.*) filter where is_deleted` instead of a case statement.

Comment: @max very nice. Unfortunately one of the places `Arel` falls short. While I haven't bothered to try at the moment (although at some point it's likely I will) I can't imagine how convoluted that expression would look written via `Arel` objects.